# Summing the Last n Cells in a row, excluding blanks, and Shifts when Numbers Inputed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I got the basics of the formula down, but it doesn't shift when I input new numbers.

The formula takes the last six numbers in the row, excluding blank cells, and sums them. I'm looking for the summation to change, but keep the previous calculations.

Here it takes the last six and changes all of them. This is tough because it involves noninputs for some cells. Here's what I have. The 43 is in cell B7 for reference. The initial summation formula is

`=IF(H$7<>"", SUM(OFFSET($B$7,0,COUNT($B$7:$AA$7)-1,,-6)), G$6)`

[image]

Any quick fixes to the formula that I can do? Remember that there is a possibility of blank cells in the future (beyond when 41 is entered).

Answer (score 0):

To sum the last 6 non-blank entries in a row, you can use the non-volatile formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B1:XFD1,-1+AGGREGATE(14,6,1/ISNUMBER(B1:XFD1)*COLUMN(B1:XFD1),{1,2,3,4,5,6})))
```

- Assumes formula might be in A1
- If formula not in the same row as the range to be summed, you could use a whole row reference (eg `1:1`)
- Note the `-1` in the columns argument

  - This compensates for the difference between the `INDEX` into the array and the column number.  Since the array starts in Column B (2nd column) we need to subtract 1.
  - If the array started in Column E (5th column) we would need to subtract 4.
  - If the array referred to the entire row, there would be no need to subtract.
- If there are less than six numbers, the formula will return a `#NUM!` error. You could compensate for this by `wrapping` the formula within an `IFERROR` function, or you could test specifically with `COUNT(arr) > 5`